# How to associate nested object (exist in database) with parent object ManyToOne relationship?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to save Student object -which has no id- to database. However, Student object has several child objects - which have id -.

How can i save parent object in **one time** without getting child objects references and mapping to parent object.

```
public class Student{
//...     
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "school_id")
School school;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
Course course;
//...
}
```

and

```
public class School {
//...     
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "school")
List<Student> students

//...
}

public class Course{
//...     
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
List<Student> students

//...
}
```

Service layer

```
public Student saveStudent(Student student) {   
 //...
 return studentRepository.save(student);

}
```

When i try to save Student object which has School object  and Course object having only id property it throws this error because of school object has no reference.

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient
> instance before flushing

If School object has version number and id number it works fine.

I don't want to update or insert new school object.

So i tried Cascade.ALL, Cascade.MERGE, Cascade.PERSIST and nothing work.
I tried override equals and hashCode based only id. Not working.

My aim is that

I have several School object in my database.
When a new student register, Student object will take School as an object.
Finally, I will save Student object and jpa will associate Student to School on School id.

Postman post example for student.

```
//failed request object sample
{
 //...
 "id":null,
 "school":{"id":12},
 "course":{"id":21}

 //...

} 
//...

//succesfull request object sample
{
 //...
 "id":null,
 "school":{"id":12, "version": 0},
 "course":{"id":21, "version": 0}

 //...

}
```

If school and course object has version(@Version) property these are merged to Student object succesfully without getting child object reference and mapping to parent.

Second post request object saved succesfully, and parent and children relation builded.

Why jpa need version to merge child and parent?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing your service layer where you're doing the save, but I suspect you aren't attaching the entities to the student.  Just setting the id on a POJO doesn't make it available to the persistence context, which is why you're getting this exception.  Read through Hibernate's documentation on the persistence context [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch03.html)

A psuedo service layer implementation would look like this:

```
public Student saveStudent(Student student) {  // where the student is the object passed in
  School school = schoolRepository.findById(student.getSchool().getId());
  Course course = courseRepository.findById(student.getCourse().getId());

  student.setCourse(course);
  student.setSchool(school);

  return studentRepository.save(student);

}
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I added some explanations. I do not want any get reference and mapping child to parent again. If ı post version property to object it merge succesfully.